# Flutter Firebase Cloud Messaging create notification inside the app

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase cloud messaging in my flutter project. When I create notification on Firebase, the notification works fine, but I also want the user to create notifications through the application, how should I do it please help.

Comment: See: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

Comment: is there no way to do this using firebase messaging?

Comment: My mistake, I did not understand your question properly. See: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage